# how to check if folder exists cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Is there any instance to return bool? e.g. $folder->exists() => bool

```
$path = WEBROOT_DIR .'/files/'. $folder_name;
$folder = new Folder('../'.$path); 
//DOESN'T WORK
debug($folder->exists());
//I can do it in this way 
//returns bool
debug(file_exists($folder->path));
```

I want to check if directory exists delete it. **but I want to use specifically cake method to check if folder exists**

Comment: Cakephp does not have exists method for Folder, just for File.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$path = 'files' . DS . $folder_name;
$folder = new Folder($path);

if (!is_null($folder->path)) {
    $folder->delete();
}
```

Comment: Yes, you want to delete the directory if it exists, is exactly what the code is doing. Have you even tried?

Comment: I clearly said it that I know this answer. I am looking for an instance to check the folder. like e.g. if ($folder->exists()) {...

Comment: If `$folder->path` is null, it not exists. What's the problem? Anyway, there is no documented method like `exists()`.

Comment: just read other other articles. new Folder($path); it self does this job. so it checks if folder exists.

Answer (score 1):

Cakephp `Folder` class does not have method `exists` like `File` class has.

You could check if the folder exists with standard php and then delete it.

```
if (file_exists('path/to/directory')) {
    rmdir('path/to/directory', 777, true);
}
```

Basically it checks if the folder exists with the [file_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) function and if the file does not exist then it will use [rmdir](https://www.php.net/rmdir) function to create the folder.

Though I think you could use cakephp like this. This will delete the folder even if the folder does not exist because the Folder constructor will create the folder if the folder does not exist.

```
$folder = new Folder('path/to/directory', true, 777);
$folder->delete();
```

Comment: Cheers mate same time updated my own answer. This will work but I wonder if I could use cake method to do so

Comment: cakephp Folder constructor can create the directory if the directory does not already exist. This requires passing true as second $create parameter as true.

Comment: I want to check if directory exists then delete it

Comment: Updated my example so that it will create the folder if it does not exist and will delete it afterwards even if the folder did not exist before creation.

Comment: what is the point then. why it has to create and then delete?

Comment: It wont create the folder if the folder already exists, this will make sure $folder->delete() returns success as true in either case.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Just read the cake ticket list cake doesn't have this instance to do so. This ticket has been closed.

Comment: Why the obsession with using a Cake method?  This is the obvious answer.  Seems kind of like saying "I want to use a cake method for determining string length", when the obvious answer would be "just use php".