# how to create directory on field name cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp

I would like to get object by id from database inside Controller then use its name to create directory with that name.

```
public function album($id = null) {
    $dirname = $this->Dog->query('SELECT * from dogs WHERE id='$id'');
    $dir = new Folder(WWW_ROOT . 'albums' . DS . 'files' . DS . $dirname->name , true, 0755);
    $this->layout = 'edit';
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Zły post'));
    }

    $Dog = $this->Dog->findById($id);
    if (!$Dog) {
    throw new NotFoundException(__('Zły post'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
    $this->Dog->id = $id;
    if ($this->Dog->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Edycja zakończona sukcesem.'));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index_psy'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Spróbuj ponownie.'));
    }
}
}
```

I have tried a few other solutions but none of them seems to work.
Thanks for help

Comment: Have you tried [debugging](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/debugging.html) the key variables to see what they contain? `$id`, `$dirname` and `$Dog`?

Comment: why do you use query instead of find?

Comment: $Dog = $this->Dog->findById($id);

Comment: When i do something like this: `$Dog = $this->Dog->findById($id); $dir = new Folder(WWW_ROOT . 'albums' . DS . 'files' . DS . $Dog->name , true, 0755);` i get "Trying to get property of non-object".

If i change `$Dog->name` to `$this->Dog->name` i always get 'dog'. Sorry for my newbie questions but i cannot understand this even tho i looked around google for a while..

Comment: because cake find() returns arrays and not objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function album($id) {
        //if id doesn't exist Exit
        if (!$this->Dog->exists($id)) {
                throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid album'));
        }
        $dog = $this->Dog->findById($id);
        //create a folder with directory name 
        $path = 'files' . DS . $dog['Dog']['name'];
        $folder = new Folder($path , true, 0755);

        $this->layout = 'edit';

    }
}
```

[look at here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22269087/how-to-check-if-folder-exists-cakephp)   just to get an idea